# Como usar funções que estão em um arquivo diferente? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um problema para usar funções que estão em um arquivo diferente do local onde estou chamando estas funções. Basicamente meu projeto está organizado da seguinte maneira:

```
Lista_I (Pacote Contendo os Arquivos)
    __init__.py
    funcoes_uteis.py
    PDI.py
```

No arquivo `PDI.py` tenho o seguinte código:

```
import numpy

def aplicar_mascara_media_aritmetica(imagem):

    filtro = numpy.zeros((3, 3))

    for i in range(1, len(imagem) - 1):
        for j in range(1, len(imagem[0]) - 1):
            filtro[0][0] = imagem[i - 1][j - 1]
            filtro[0][1] = imagem[i - 1][j]
            filtro[0][2] = imagem[i - 1][j + 1]
            filtro[1][0] = imagem[i][j - 1]
            filtro[1][1] = imagem[i][j]
            filtro[1][2] = imagem[i][j + 1]
            filtro[2][0] = imagem[i + 1][j - 1]
            filtro[2][1] = imagem[i + 1][j]
            filtro[2][2] = imagem[i + 1][j + 1]

            imagem[i][j] = calcular_media(filtro) #não funciona

    return imagem
```

E no arquivo `funcoes_uteis.py` eu tenho a função `calcular_media(filtro)` que está sendo chamada no arquivo `PDI.py`. Já tentei fazer `import funcoes_uteis` mas não está funcionando. Não sei se isto tem a ver com a versão do python que estou usando, mas por via das dúvidas, estou utilizando a versão 3.6 do python.
Alguém pode me ajudar com este problema? Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `PDI.py` adicione:

```
import funcoes_uteis
```

E chame:

```
imagem[i][j] = funcoes_uteis.calcular_media(filtro)
```

Ou se não quiser usa como `funcoes_uteis.calcular_media` chame assim:

```
from funcoes_uteis import calcular_media
```

E chame:

```
imagem[i][j] = calcular_media(filtro)
```

---

Criei dois scripts de teste bem simples

**PDI.py**

```
import funcoes_uteis

def aplicar_mascara_media_aritmetica():
    return funcoes_uteis.calcular_media(2)

print(aplicar_mascara_media_aritmetica())
```

**funcoes_uteis.py**

```
def calcular_media(imagem):
    return imagem
```

E então executei no cmd:

[image: exemplo]

Comment: Tentei fazer das duas formas, mas nenhuma delas funcionou

Comment: @CloudAC não funcionou é muito ambíguo e não me diz nada a respeito para que eu entenda aonde foi a falha, que erro que deu na tela?

Comment: "No module named funcoes_uteis". É como se ele não tivesse enxergando o arquivo.

Comment: @CloudAC editei a resposta, veja a parte do exemplo e o teste que fiz em meu computador, você provavelmente se confundiu em algo.

Comment: @CloudAC Quem executa o teu script python? É o Django/Flask ou está usando com wsgi e Apache?

Comment: então, eu instalei o python a partir do Anaconda 4.4.0 e estava executando os scripts com a IDE PyCharm. Mas tentei agora executar o script direto pelo cmd do windows e obtive o mesmo problema

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65677/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-cloudac).

Comment: desinstalei tudo sobre python que tinha na minha máquina e reinstalei. Agora ta funcionando normal do jeito que você ensinou, obrigado por responder e pela paciência!